# Export armature animation + corrective smooth modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers, rigging

Here I have a rat rigged and animated,And I used a corrective smooth modifier.
But I am going to export this animation into unity,SO my question here,how can I export this animation including the corrective smooth modifier effect to and external app like unity?or can we do the corrective smooth by another way?

Comment: DO you even have to export your character for working with Unity? As far as I know, you can also just import your .blend-files into unity and work with them. The advantages are obvisouly, you can update your blend file at any time and it will be always up to date in your unity project.

Comment: But I dont think it will work like that,I mean how unity know about the new corrective smooth anyway.

Comment: @Slim Marten that’s just Unity communication, their '.blend file reading' actually opens .blend file with Blender and export it as an FBX file (old 6.1 ASCII even!), and import that FBX in Unity…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is quite simple: you cannot. Corrective smoothness is very advanced effect that simply cannot be exported, nor baked at the moment.

Only way to bake that I can think of, anyway, would be (with e.g. a py script), for each frame, to make a diff between the mesh with and without CS modifier, and store that diff in a relative shapekey, and then animate all those skeys such that they each express at one frame.

But this sounds like an awfully heavy solution to me. And result is not much guaranteed even, since shapekeys are applied **before** the armature modifier (and the whole modifier stack), while Corrective smoothness modifier comes **after** the armature modifier…

Comment: Ok I will use the normal method by reweighting the bones.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem, I created an add-on, which bakes corrective smooth modifier to vertex weights, then you can export the character to game engines.
https://www.blendermarket.com/products/corrective-smooth-baker